CMOS transmission gate model for intermediate control voltages
I want to model a CMOS transmission gate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate) in my own simulation (a numerical solution of some ordinary differential equations). For this I need a (static) model of how the voltage-current relationship in the output path depends on the control voltage (w.r.t. some reference voltage, I'm not sure about this one yet). It is not sufficient in my case to model the behavior for only two control voltages (low/high, for which the output path is basically a off/on switch), since the transition of the output for intermediate control voltages is relevant.
I would be grateful if someone could point me to a publication or could provide an idea how I could derive some model (even if it is simplified to some extent).

Edit (in response to Dave Tweed): My application is something like a sample-and-hold circuit. A simplified case would be the following: An input voltage (to be sampled) is connected to a transmission gate, a resistor, and a capacitor in series. For intermediate voltages of the control input (which I assumed is a joint control input with negator included as you described), the capacitor should charge or discharge more slowly, in contrast to providing a well-defined high and low control voltage, where we would have a time constant of RC or close to infinity, respectively.

A transmission gate requires two control voltages. The second one is normally derived from the first using an ordinary CMOS digital inverter, which is going to have very nonlinear behavior WRT "intermediate control voltages". Which means that modeling the transmission channel is not going to be reducible to a single parameter. This is similar to another conversation I had recently. Developing a useful model depends very much on exactly what you hope to learn from using it. Please describe what you're trying to do in more detail.

@DaveTweed: I edited my question to provide more details. The specific question would be: how does the control voltage affect the time constant of the S&H circuit. I guess it's much more complex than I imagined.
